# Submitting a job to Apache Spark Error

Tags: apache-spark

I have the following settings for my Apache Spark instance that runs locally on my machine:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/Users/joe/Softwares/apache/spark/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=127.0.0.1
export SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077
export SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=8080
export SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=$SPARK_HOME/work
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_INSTANCES=2
export SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY=384m
```

I have a spark streaming consumer that I would like to submit to Spark. This streaming consumer is just a jar file that I submit like this:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class com.my.job.MetricsConsumer --master spark://127.0.0.1:7077 /Users/joe/Sandbox/jaguar/spark-kafka-consumer/target/scala-2.11/spark-kafka-consumer-0.1.0-SNAPAHOT.jar
```

I get the following error:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/01/13 10:30:06 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.0
16/01/13 10:30:06 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

16/01/13 10:30:06 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: joe
16/01/13 10:30:06 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: joe
16/01/13 10:30:06 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(joe); users with modify permissions: Set(joe)
16/01/13 10:30:07 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 65528.
16/01/13 10:30:07 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
16/01/13 10:30:08 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/01/13 10:30:08 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@172.22.0.104:65529]
16/01/13 10:30:08 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 65529.
16/01/13 10:30:08 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/01/13 10:30:08 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/01/13 10:30:08 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /Users/joe/Softwares/apache/spark/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/work/blockmgr-cee3388d-ecfc-42a7-a76c-8738401db0c9
16/01/13 10:30:08 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 511.1 MB
16/01/13 10:30:08 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/01/13 10:30:08 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/01/13 10:30:08 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://172.22.0.104:4040
16/01/13 10:30:08 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /Users/joe/Softwares/apache/spark/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/work/spark-10d7d880-7d1d-4234-88d4-d80558c8051a/httpd-40f80936-7508-4b6c-bb90-411aa37d7e93
16/01/13 10:30:08 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
16/01/13 10:30:08 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 65530.
16/01/13 10:30:09 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/Users/joe/Sandbox/jaguar/spark-kafka-consumer/target/scala-2.11/spark-kafka-consumer-0.1.0-SNAPAHOT.jar at http://172.22.0.104:65530/jars/spark-kafka-consumer-0.1.0-SNAPAHOT.jar with timestamp 1452677409966
16/01/13 10:30:10 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://myhost:7077...
16/01/13 10:30:10 WARN AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master myhost:7077
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to myhost:7077
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:216)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:183)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:101)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:622)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:209)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.connect(AbstractNioChannel.java:207)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1097)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:471)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:456)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.connect(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:47)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:471)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:456)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.connect(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:50)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:471)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:456)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:438)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:908)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.connect(AbstractChannel.java:203)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$2.run(Bootstrap.java:166)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    ... 1 more
```

I have checked my firewall settings and eveything seems to be Ok. Why would I get this error? Any ideas?

Comment: While submitting the applications in Standalone mode, the value of parameter "--master" should be same as it is shown on Spark Master UI. Can you confirm that it is same?

Comment: @Sumit mine's is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353361/spark-cluster-could-not-connet